# UITableView contentInset makes table view scroll horizontally in addition to vertically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitableview

I'm creating a UITableViewController in code and pushing it on top of the navigation stack. 
It's table view is intended to just show a simple list of text items.

I need to add some contentInset to my table view which I add in the init method of my UITableViewController

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7.0f, 5.0f, 7.0f, 5.0f);
```

However, when I load the table view it seems the left and right contentInset have actually stretched the width of my table view by 10. I'm now seeing a small horizontal scrollable area. I don't want any sort of horizontal scrolling on my table view. If I remove the contentInset code, my table view behaves plainly i.e. simply provides for vertical scrolling. How I can keep just like that but with my contentInset in place? I tried reducing my contentSize.width by 10 in viewWillAppear, it had no effect.

This seems to be a duplicate but with no acceptable answer: [UITableView ContentInsets scrolling content horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951196/uitableview-contentinsets-scrolling-content-horizontally)

In the mock I have marked the desired contentInset with dashed line ---

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to achieve the effect of having a border around the table view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll add a screenshot...

Comment: The border got me thinking.. I tried using tableView.layer to set borderColor and Width, however, I'm losing the cell border because the tableView border overlays on that. Is there any clean way of getting it to work like the mock? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Will adding the table view in a container view give the effect you're looking for?

Comment: I want the insets to scroll away too. The way I have it setup currently is using UITableViewController as the whole VC. If only I could get the contentInset to work that'll be awesome! At present the right inset appears just off the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up setting just the top and bottom insets. To achieve the left and right inset look and feel, I created custom cell as wide as the screen. But the actual cell content was restricted to a slightly narrower subview within the custom cell. Thus, there was space leftover on the left and right of the subview.

Comment: It works until you had a section header which won't be inset like your cells. Of course you could do the same trick for your header but it starts to feel incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do 2 things:

1. Add the table view to a container view and make the table view `frame` thinner (to add the left and right borders).
2. Add the`contentInset` only for the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had to subclass UITableViewController therefore adding a container into its view (tableView) seemed too complicated. I got the visual insets by customizing the cell view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the bounces property of the scrollView to YES.
And do not set the contentInset.

Comment: You should not use contentInsets to generate border, if you do this, your border will be displayed outside the view!

Answer (score 0):

Another way that could work, is that, instead of setting the `tableView` frame, you can set the frame for cell's `contentView` , something like this,

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width * 0.9; //90% of total width
    frame.origin.x = self.center.x - (frame.size.width/2); //center the contentView
    self.contentView.frame = frame;
}
```

The using the above, u can add any left or right or left padding u need for the cell. and all the subViews will be added to the `contentView` , hence no problems there.

happy coding..!